# How to delete hidden hard drive sectors?

Tags: windows-7, disk-space, privacy

I'm trying to wipe a drive but I found out what I've been using (DBAN) doesn't delete hidden parts of the hard drive (Host Protected Area). What do I do to delete them?

Comment: What's DNAN? A sort of deleting or erasing software? There are so many. I'm not sure what you mean about deleting sectors either. The space on any disk is never ever deleted, not even with software. You cannot delete; it's a concept. It's like throwing out the garbage, it's really asking someone to put it somewhere where you can't see it.

Comment: DBAN maybe? (since N and B are next to each other). The question is what hidden parts are you thinking of? If you can explain a bit more about it? Mind you, any "secure erase" of a drive basically over-writing the sector of the drive multiple times to the point it is almost impossible to recover.

Comment: Yes I meant DBAN, and the oarts DBAN doesn't delete (or erase, idk) are these: https://www.google.ie/url?q=http://scholar.google.com/scholar_url%3Furl%3Dhttp://www.media-clone.net/v/vspfiles/downloads/hpadco.pdf%26hl%3Den%26sa%3DX%26scisig%3DAAGBfm2V6D3hejV89BaLc4_Qi4nEEM2vdQ%26nossl%3D1%26oi%3Dscholarr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3wcWz-JbNAhXqAcAKHcUGAlMQgAMIGSgAMAA&usg=AFQjCNGXNke7x7Zv6FO-HYKx9RndhdU4-g

Comment: @James The areas mentioned in that article you linked to are normally not usable/visible to the Operating System. It takes special tools to intentionally read/write information there. DBAN will not wipe them, but the question is why would you want to do that in the 1st place? If you have a drive that you want to sell and on which you placed data yourself there, you can wipe (zero-overwrite) it in the same way. If you got a disk from someone else that you don't trust a normal DBAN should be enough. Your PC will not read anything from that hidden area by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Any good tool can compeltely erase the content of a HDD. Try something like 
HDD eraser: http://www.harddriveeraser.org
You can securely erases whole volumes, disk drives or partitions...so nothing will escape intact with such a tool.

Comment: I will try hdd eraser now. Does anyone know for sure if it deletes everything?

Comment: It does, I tested it a long time ago when clients wanted proof/confirmation of data deletion.

Answer (score 0):

If your pleasure is totally wiping the content, in hopes that mut even NSA can't recover even parts of the content, 1st r remember we don't know for sure how efficient their methods have, so I can only estimate that the best methods likely work.
2nd, the application must support overwriting the partition, or disk multiple times with rubbish (overwrite a file once with random bytes, and the old data can be read with tools anyone has access).

I remember in the early 2000's overwriting 7 times with zeros was considered enough, but last time I checked, zeros weren't good, as we're not any one digit - the program needs to use a random value for every byte, word or long, and the minimum recommended number of repeating it was 10, but obviously more times the better - I would use even 100, except on SSD (solid state drive - common on n netbooks, also memory sticks and cards; like sd-card familiar from mobile devices) as they have a limit on how many writes each byte on the memory can stand before it stops working - so buy high classification sd-cards

;P

Comment: This is kind of a rambling opinion piece that isn't factually accurate and doesn't really address what was asked in the question.  You might want to reread the question.